# Сбой в работе ПКМ

Tags: диск, пк

При нажатии на ПКМ на жёсткий диск, комп зависает и не перезагружается без посторонней помощи.

Answer (score 1):

Ставили какие-нибудь программы или обновляли драйвера? Была похожая проблема из-за того что драйвера видеокарты intel (вернее, сопутствующее ПО) пытались куда-то обратиться на сайт и вешали весь комп. Изначально просто передергивали ethernet-кабель. Потом нашли и вырвали с корнем пункты, начинающиеся с igfx, в контекстном меню(через реестр) и заодно выпилили значки из Панели управления (*.cpl в системном каталоге)

Comment: Все же добавлю, что пункты контекстного меню храянтся в HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\*, но все же прежде чем удалять лишнее стоит сохранить(экспортировать) нужную ветку реестра.